# Boot warning/error message

Tags: 12.04, boot, external-hdd

I have an external 2TB Western Digital hdd (besides my 2 internal hdds, so this makes hime /dev/sdc). After loading grub, I have seen a quick error message.

After checking the log file: /var/log/boot.log I can see it more clearly:

```
xxx@xxx:~$ cat /var/log/boot.log 
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
ata_id[698]: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sdc': Invalid argument
```

Any  thoughts? Should I be worried?

Comment: You are not booting from your external drive, are you?

Comment: no, no. It's just a new back-up drive

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google for "HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for" revealed this;

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1015693

To summarize,

```
Drive errors in the system log files
    /dev/sda: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Invalid argument

    This error is produced by hdparm when using the -i switch on some SCSI and SATA disk drives. hdparm was not designed to be used with SCSI or SATA drives. No tweaks that hdparm can provide are needed for SCSI or SATA drives.

    Fix: Disable any Cpanel IDE hard drive tweaks and remove any hdparm settings in local startup files.
```

It sounds like it's not important and can likely be ignored.

Comment: Thx for the link. I will study it, and get back to you later. Now I am at work.